# setState Warning in child component. Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a page which presents a list of projects, when a user clicks on that particular project a view component is called in the `render()`.

Parent :

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showData : [],
      view : false,
      projectId: ''
    };
    this.buttonHandler = this.buttonHandler.bind(this);
    this.back = this.back.bind(this);
  };


// change view state to true to render diff component
    buttonHandler(){
    this.setState({view:true})
  };



  back(){

    this.setState({view:true})
  }

 render(){

   let compA = (
  <Paper>
        <List>
            <Subheader >New 
            Projects</Subheader>
            {this.state.showData.map(item =>
                <div key={item.title}>
                    <ListItem onClick={()=> 
                   this.buttonHandler()} leftAvatar=
                   {<Avatar icon={<Wallpaper />} />} primaryText=
                   "test" secondaryText="test" />
                    <Divider inset={true} />
                </div>
            )}
        </List>
    </Paper>
);

let compB = (
  <ReviewProject
    back={this.back}/>
);
  return(
      <div>
        {this.state.view?compB:compA}
      </div>
    );
}
```

child comp B :

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
this.state = {
//some code
};

}
//calls function back from parent which sets state the "view" to false
 dismiss() {
    this.props.back();
  };
```

When the `dismiss()` function is called at the child to render back the list component `compA`, a warning pops out:

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the compB component.
```

Is there a way to solve this? and what is a good practice to navigate from one component to the other back and forth

Comment: how do you call the dismiss function, and can you add the definition for back function

Comment: If you can use `routes` to render different components, that would be good.

Comment: I call the dismiss function at compB, which then sets the state of view in compA to false. I have re edited

Comment: You assigned true in the back function, you should be setting it to false

Comment: @Panther, hmm yea, but what if I just want the state of the parent to render a component based on the value of the state is what im trying to achieve. It's working but it throws me the warning

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, I'm already getting my desired output its just that it keeps throwing me the warning, which is what I want to resolve

Comment: Usually this warning occurs if an function is called from within `render` or within render's context. The code shown looks good. Might be you have to look at `ReviewProject` to see how you are calling the `back` function.

Comment: How are you calling the dismiss function within component B

Comment: @Panther, dismiss() function is triggered with an onTouchTap. <FlatButton onTouchTap={this.dismiss} primary={true} label="Back"/>

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, triggered by an onTouchTap. I have also declared the binding in the constructor of compB

Comment: can you show your stacktrace for this warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is:

To create a third component called `viewProject` component to handle the switching between `A` and `B`.

```
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        This is component A
        <button onClick={this.props.onGoBClick}>Go to B</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class B extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        This is component B
        <button onClick={this.props.onGoAClick}>Go to A</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ViewContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      view: false,
    }
    this.goToA = this.goToA.bind(this);
    this.goToB = this.goToB.bind(this);
  }

  goToA() {
    this.setState({view: false})
  }

  goToB() {
    this.setState({view: true})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.view ?
        <B onGoAClick={this.goToA}/>
      :
        <A onGoBClick={this.goToB}/>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ViewContainer />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ref also before setting your state as defined below
function(){

```
 if (this.refs.ref) 
   this.setState({view: true});
}

render() {
  return (
    <div ref="ref">{this.state.view}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have already bind dismiss. Also my buttonHandler() is bind to a onTouchTap, so when triggered it will render compB instead of compA which I initially declared state.view as false. I'm already achieving my desired output , it's just that I keep getting the Warning. Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Answer (score 0):

Because actually on first render, it's kind of if compA is rendered, then compB is missing, therefore when the react tries to re-render, it cannot find the missing element.

==> **SOLUTION**:

```
render(){                            
    let returnedComp = (
      <Paper>
            <List>
                <Subheader >New Projects</Subheader>
                {this.state.showData.map(item =>
                    <div key={item.title}>
                        <ListItem onClick={()=> 
                       this.buttonHandler()} leftAvatar=
                       {<Avatar icon={<Wallpaper />} />} primaryText=
                       "test" secondaryText="test" />
                        <Divider inset={true} />
                    </div>
                )}
            </List>
        </Paper>
    );

        if (this.state.view) {
            returnedComp = (
              <ReviewProject back={this.back}/>
            );
        }
      return(
          <div>
            {returnedComp}
          </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: Initially this.state.view is false, which in turn will render compA on the first render. When buttonHandler is triggered by an onTouchTap it setStates the view to true which will then trigger the re-render. {this.state.view?compB:compA} is if this.state.view is true then compB else compA. Thanks but I dont think this will resolve my warning

Comment: Could you please try this, or have you tried it already? Your logic sounds fine, however the problem is react and jsx will have their own rule! The above answer was copied from my real code, which fixed my previous nearly same issue!

Comment: Yea I just tried it and I'm still getting the same warning. I believe it has something to do with me calling a setState from an unmounted component. Thanks for suggestion anyway.